# How do I extract the datas from two .txt files into one new .txt file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

Let's say I have two .txt files now called A.txt and B.txt.

In A.txt, the data is as followed:

```
ABCD12340100000002

0000AB195831 2014082700000000   
0000AB195831 2014082700000000
```

In the second file, B.txt, the data is as followed:

```
ABCD12340100000003

0000AB195831 2014082700000000        
0000AB195831 2014082700000000   
0000AB195831 2014082700000000
```

So in the new C.txt file I would like to have the data as followed:

```
ABCD12340100000005

0000AB195831 2014082700000000        
0000AB195831 2014082700000000   
0000AB195831 2014082700000000  
0000AB195831 2014082700000000        
0000AB195831 2014082700000000
```

This means that I extracted all the rows in the A.txt and B.txt files and put them together but for
the first row, from the 11th position onwards, it means the number of the rows in that .txt file and
I would like to write a batch file to help to compute the number of rows in A and the number of rows in B together and come out with the number of rows in C (A + B = C -> 00000002 + 00000003 = 00000005)

So, how do I write the batch file so that I can extract it accordingly and create a new .txt file which is called C.txt?

Comment: What operating system? Unix? Windows?

Comment: @MarkStewart Windows.

Comment: If you have any option at all, do not try to use batch for this. Do it in powershell, python, ruby, anything else.

Comment: @Blorgbeard But is it possible to do it using batch?

Comment: Probably. But it won't be fun to write or read or maintain.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Can you guide me in how to use batch to do this because the requirement is only by using batch.

Comment: @Blorgbeard You can also show me how it is done using powershell. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (q27162517b.txt) DO SET "L2a=%%a"&SET "L1a="&GOTO nextstep
 :nextstep
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27162517a.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED L1a (ECHO(%%a) ELSE (SET "L1a=%%a"&CALL :sumlines)
)
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%a IN (q27162517b.txt) DO (ECHO(%%a)
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:sumlines
SET /a L2a=1%L1a:~11%+1%L2a:~11%
ECHO(%L1a:~0,10%%L2a:~1%
ECHO(
GOTO :eof
```

Simple enough - where's the problem?

I used your data in `q27162517a.txt` and `q27162517b.txt` producing `newfile.txt` - change the names to suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to get the same result. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get first line of A.txt and B.txt
set /P "lineA=" < A.txt
set /P "lineB=" < B.txt

rem Perform the sum
set /A "sum= 1%lineA:~10% + 1%lineB:~10%"

rem Generate C.txt
(
   echo %lineA:~0,10%%sum:~1%
   echo/
   more +2 A.txt
   more +2 B.txt
) > C.txt
```